# VueJs - wait for OPTION response before page reload

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to make a put request to backend when a user closes or refreshes the page. I've added the event listeners and I can run my functions when those events happen. But my problem is when those functions send a put request, they send an option request first, then send the put request. And this is a problem for me because when I check the backend logs I see that option request is received by the server (and gets 200 status code) but put request is not.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        App
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios"

    export default {
        name: "App",
        mounted() {
            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.reload)
        },
        methods: {
            reload() {
                this.sendRequest()
            },
            sendRequest() {
                axios.put("http://xxxx:pp")
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple workaround is to use `post` instead of `put` and avoid the `options` request altogether.  From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control):

> Cross-site requests are preflighted like this... if:
>
> - It uses methods other than GET or POST

If you don't want to do that, you'll need to handle the `options` request at the backend server by supplying CORS headers.